# Swap two letters in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to swap two letters in a string. For example, if input is `W` and `H` then all the occurrences of `W` in string should be replaced by `H` and all the occurrences of `H` should be replaced by `W`. String `WelloHorld` will become `HelloWorld`.

I know how to replace single char:

```
str = str.replace('W', 'H');
```

But I am not able to figure out how to swap characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would probably need three replace calls to get this done.

The first one to change one of the characters to an intermediate value, the second to do the first replace, and the third one to replace the intermediate value with the second replacement.

```
String str = "Hello World";

str = star.replace("H", "*").replace("W", "H").replace("*", "W");
```

**Edit**

In response to some of the concerns below regarding the correctness of this method of swapping characters in a `String`. This will work, even when there is a `*` in the `String` already. However, this requires the additional steps of first escaping any occurrence of `*` and un-escaping these before returning the new `String`.

```
public static String replaceCharsStar(String org, char swapA, char swapB) {
    return org
            .replace("*", "\\*")
            .replace(swapA, '*')
            .replace(swapB, swapA)
            .replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\*", "" + swapB)
            .replace("\\*", "*");

}
```

**Edit 2**

After reading through some the other answers, a new version, that doesn't just work in Java 8, works with replacing characters which need to be escaped in regex, e.g. `[` and `]` and takes into account concerns about using `char` primitives for manipulating `String` objects.

```
public static String swap(String org, String swapA, String swapB) {
    String swapAEscaped = swapA.replaceAll("([\\[\\]\\\\+*?(){}^$])", "\\\\$1");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(org.length());

    String[] split = org.split(swapAEscaped);

    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        builder.append(split[i].replace(swapB, swapA));
        if (i != (split.length - 1)) {
            builder.append(swapB);
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();

}
```

Comment: What if the string already contains '*' ? Then the unwanted characters are modified.

Comment: In that case you'd have to use an alternative intermediate character. It is best to pick something obscure if this would be used in production code, I probably should have added that as a warning.

Comment: If we have guarantee that some characters are not used then we can pick one among them. Otherwise its better to loop through characters and modify them based on the condition.

Comment: Of course you could check for the presence of these characters. The point being that this is an alternative to looping through the `String`. Which one is prefer would depend on the situation it is to be used. In the case of a simple `Hello World` case at this, it doesn't really matter. But then again, looping the a `char` array is not ideal with languages where a single character might be encoded in multiple `char`s.

Comment: @PeterK - Your answer is right, but the problem is it is less efficient (in terms of both memory and time) when compared to a simple loop solution. Your answer is O(n) + O(n) + O(n).

Comment: @TheLostMind, I understand your concern, the reason for posting this answer was not to suggest it is better than the array answer already present, but merely to provide an alternative that uses the `replace` function that Jaguar mentioned.

Comment: Rather than the efficiency, I'd worry about the fact that `*` might be already inside the string (as mentioned earlier). Without a check to handle that this code is broken.

Comment: This is still broken: `replaceCharsStar("\\ABC", 'A', 'C')` yields `*BA` instead of `\CBA`

Comment: On top of that, as I mentioned in my answer, `char`s cannot handle all possible letters: `replaceCharsStar("bc", "".charAt(0), "c".charAt(0))` yields `c?b?` instead of `cb`

Answer (score 8):

```
public String getSwappedString(String s)
{
char ac[] = s.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
   if(ac[i] == 'H')
     ac[i]='W';
   else if(ac[i] == 'W')
     ac[i] = 'H'; 
}

s = new String(ac);
return s;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

With Java8 it's truly simple

```
static String swap(String str, String one, String two){
    return Arrays.stream(str.split(one, -1))
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll(two, one))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(two));
}
```

Usage example:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    System.out.println(swap("", "", ""));
}
```

I urge you not to use a `Character` for the swap function, since it will break strings containing letters outside the BMP

In case you want to extend this to work with arbitrary Strings (not only letters), you can just quote the supplied strings:

```
static String swap(String str, String one, String two){
    String patternOne = Pattern.quote(one);
    String patternTwo = Pattern.quote(two);
    return Arrays.stream(str.split(patternOne, -1))
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll(patternTwo, one))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(two));
}
```

Comment: Throws `PatternSyntaxException` when attempting to swap `[` and `]` in `hello[world]`

Comment: Since the question asked about splitting letters, I didn't bother to make it work with other characters... You can check what codepoints Java holds as letters: `Character.isLetter('[')` is `false`, while `Character.isLetter(Character.toCodePoint("".charAt(0), "".charAt(1)))` is `true`... anyhow this can be trivially fixed

Answer (score 3):

A slightly nicer version of the string-scanning approach, without explicit arrays and index access:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : source_string.toCharArray()) {
  if (c == 'H') sb.append("W");
  else if (c == 'W') sb.append("H");
  else sb.append(c);
}
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over the String's character array, and swap whenever you see either of the characters:

```
private static String swap(String str, char one, char two) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] == one) {
            chars[i] = two;
        } else if (chars[i] == two) {
            chars[i] = one;
        }
    }
    return String.valueOf(chars);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this code also.

```
System.out.println("WelloHorld".replaceAll("W", "H~").replaceAll("H(?!~)", "W").replaceAll("(?<=H)~", ""));
```

Output:

```
HelloWorld
```

Use any character which isn't present in the input string instead of `~`.